# Windows Local Static IP Address Changes While Computer is Running

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

I have my Windows 10 local server set to have a static local IP address of `10.0.1.19` through my wireless router based on the mac address of the computer's wireless adapter. For the past several months, it's been working just fine, but tonight, out of the blue, the computer's local IP address magically changed to `192.168.1.3` while it was running (checked IPV4 via `ipconfig \all`). I restarted the computer and it went back to `10.0.1.19`, but after around 10 minutes it happened again. Rather than restarting the computer this time, I simply unplugged the wireless dongle and plugged it back in, which also fixed it.

The IP change happened both times while several other computers were connected to the server (and this sudden change screwed up their connections). This has never happened during the past few months I've been doing this, and nothing I'm aware of was different this time. **What could cause a local static IP address to suddenly change like that?** Has anybody experienced this? I don't understand how the IP address could change given that I set it to be static through the router (remember, it goes back to its static address once restarting the computer *or* re-inserting the network adapter). This makes me think that Windows decided to change it for some reason, but I don't know.

Here is some additional information which may or may not be relevant; I have no idea:

I was running a Python server on the main computer that manages my renders for 3d animations by distributing work out to available client machines. For example, I had 4 other laptops running Python clients connected to the server through TCP port 9999 to send the server messages (each laptop sends approximately 600 bytes every 3 seconds). Additionally, each laptop is running a 3d rendering program which is referencing files on the main server through Windows network discovery (i.e, with paths like `\\server-name\c\file.c4d`). Essentially, there were a lot of connections being made to the server simultaneously when the IP switch happened (hence why I noticed it).

I have the router's DHCP lease settings set to 598 days, and this was initially set less than a year ago. The router is an Apple Airport Time Capsule.

I have not been able to re-create this issue. It just happened totally out of nowhere twice tonight and then magically went away without me doing anything. I have no idea if this will ever happen again, but my goal is just to gain some understanding of what could have possibly happened because I'm utterly clueless. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other wireless networks saved? The most likely cause here is another network becomes available and for whatever reason your PC "moves" to that one. It is a completely different subnet it is getting, so it is likely coming from a different SSID.

Comment: @acejavelin, genius! I just checked and sure enough, that's exactly what happened!